# Copy 2 Git Repo Histories To New Parent Directory (I Think)

Tags: git

I have `.git` repos in `foo/bar` and `foo/baz`. The projects began as separate projects but have since become identical.

I now want to "copy" the two existing repos into the parent directory `foo`. I've been reading up on subtree, filter, merging, moving, etc but I don't know what is the right thing to do.

I'm guessing I would create a new `.git` repo in the parent `foo` and "copy" the histories of both `foo/bar` and `foo/baz` into `foo`. Neither of the existing repos have branches.

If that's right, how do I go about doing it?

I don't want to delete the `foo/bar` and `foo/baz` histories. I just want to copy those histories into the new parent repo and continue committing to `foo`.

Comment: To clarify, these two projects now contain the exact same files, so if you have a `foo/bar/quux` and `foo/baz/quux`, they will both be identical and you don't care about which one you wind up with? Or do you want a project `foo` that has subdirectories `bar` and `baz`, each of which contain the files from those two original repos?

Comment: If the history of both repositories has diverged significantly, there is no easy way to merge into one. The only thing I would do is keep both in separate branches. Just create a new branch in `bar`, push there from `baz` and move `bar` to parent directory. `foo/baz` then can be safely deleted.

Comment: @BrianCampbell They each began as different repos but eventually became the same. Initially commits for each were different. Then eventually the commits became identical. So right now I commit once to each repo with the same comment. I didn't foresee this (I guess the force isn't strong in me). What about creating a new repo in the parent `foo` and just committing to that one? Will it recognize the other two repos automatically?

Comment: @FrankDraws You didn't quite answer my question. In the current HEAD commit in each of the repos, do they contain the exact same set of files, or are there different files in each one, and you need to preserve some files from one and some from the other?

Comment: @BrianCampbell Sorry. They're different files. One repo is all html, the other repo is css, js, fonts, and images. I'd like to preserve all files. The directories were set up automatically by Microsoft Communicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless or not whether there are conflicts, they can be resolved (quite clumsily though with no common ancestors, but nevertheless).

So, assuming the only branches in `bar` and `baz` are both called `master`, we do:

```
$ cd /path/to/foo
$ git init
$ git remote add bar bar
$ git remote add baz baz
$ git fetch bar master:bar
$ git fetch baz master:baz
```

At this point you have a new `foo` repository with an empty branch `master`, a branch `bar` with the contents from the `foo/bar` repository and a branch `baz` with the contents from the `foo/baz` repository.

```
$ git merge bar
$ git merge baz
```

At this point, you may get merge conflicts if there are any files with the same name that had different contents. Example output:

```
Auto-merging somefile.txt
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in somefile.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

At this point somefile.txt will contain the contents of both versions. Resolve the conflicts as usual and do

```
$ git commit
```

to finish the merge.

As a result you now have a `master` branch with the history of both `bar` and `baz` joining up at merge commit you just created. You also still have branches `bar` and `baz` and the remotes `bar` and `baz`. You can get rid of them if you like.